# How to check log for android app using phonegap

Tags: android, ios, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am new with ios and android with phonegap development.
I want to check log for android app using phonegap run on command line.

I am trying  create a application and i am not able to check log using phonegap. I am using it by command line argument with following commands:

```
phonegap run android
phonegap build
phonegap emulate android
```

Is there any way to check log with phonegap or other way to test it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome inspect to view the console log. In a chrome browser follow the instructions here:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

I do this with cordova on my android phone.